# ReplaceWith in class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

i got multiple input type file and i want to make a checking if the file max size exceeds the limit it clears the value of the `input` file. if i use the `id` if runs perfectly but when i change it to `class`
i got error like this
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`...
 this is the script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" ></script>
<input type="file" id="myFile2" class="upload" />
<input type="file" id="myFile1" class="upload" />
<input type="file" id="myFile3" class="upload" />


<script>
console.log("initiated");
var max_fileupload = 5899999;//5mb

$(".upload").bind('change', function(){
if(this.files[0].size > max_fileupload){
 alert("attachment file size is greater than maximum file size required");
 console.log($(this).val());
 $(this).replaceWith( $(this).clone( true ) );
}
});

</script>
```

is this possible using the class of the `input` file?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried removing left side assignment, that causes the error?

```
 $(this).replaceWith( $(this).clone(true) );
```

Comment: Good advice. I laughed.

Comment: You're welcome. Accept the answer as the correct answer ;) Thank you